# Flutter Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Tags: dart, flutter

**How to fix this error**

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception:
> FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1) E/flutter
> (11841):  E/flutter (11841): ^ E/flutter (11841):  E/flutter (11841):
>
> ## 0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:1357:5) E/flutter (11841):
>
> ## 1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:510:7) E/flutter (11841):
>
> ## 2      _parseJson (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:30:10) E/flutter (11841): #3      JsonDecoder.convert
>
> (dart:convert/json.dart:491:36) E/flutter (11841): #4
> JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:149:41) E/flutter (11841): #5
> storeSync (package:reborn_next_job02/Cache/syncApi.dart:19:29)
> E/flutter (11841):  E/flutter (11841): #6
> _ListPageState.initState. (package:reborn_next_job02/ui/AssetRegisters.dart:54:9) E/flutter
> (11841): #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
> E/flutter (11841): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19) E/flutter (11841): #9
> _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7) E/flutter (11841): #10     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:968:26) E/flutter (11841): #11
> _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13) E/flutter (11841): #12     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19) E/flutter (11841): #13     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback. (dart:async/zone.dart:952:26) E/flutter (11841): #14
> _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19) E/flutter (11841): #15     _Timer._handleMessage
> (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5) E/flutter (11841): #16
> _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)

**syncApi.dart**

```
storeSync(String url, String token) async {
  final response = await http.get(
    '$url/v1.0/SyncDataTable',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
  );


  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  SyncModel model = SyncModel.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  int length = model.data.length;

HelperSync().display()).elementAt(i)?.syn_ChangeSequence,


  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ((await HelperSync().display()).elementAt(i)?.syn_TableName == model.data[i].syn_TableName) {
      if ((await HelperSync().display()).elementAt(i)?.syn_ChangeSequence != model.data[i].syn_ChangeSequence) {
        switch (i) {
          case 21:
            {
              await HelperDatabase1().storeRegister(url, token);
            }
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"FormatException" errors are usually caused by encoding issues. To solve this issue, you can cast `response.body` as a HashMap to look for the resulting Map<String, dynamic> before decoding.

```dart
// final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body); // we can skip
SyncModel model = SyncModel.fromJson(response.body as Map<String, dynamic>>);
```